# Window cmd in trascoding process

Tags: vb6, forms, ffmpeg, converters

i'm tryng to capture the data from a cmd process  (read the last line of a trascoding process show in a window type comman line, to put the bitrate data into a vb6 form with this data build a remainnig time and the progress) the expert WQW send me a source code using the scripting host object model. with this line i can capture the last line ,

```
With New WshShell
    Set oExec = .Exec("tasklist.exe")
End With
```

but appear a little window type command line ,i must to do thix process each 10 second , because i need capture the real bitrate , which change all time, so you can imagine the screen in the window each time.... how can i quit the screen of these window , i try to put in the line ,vbminimized but don't work , i finish my high scholl and this is my project ,somebody help me.. thanks every body , excuse for my english it's freak i'm from L.A

Comment: A High School project and you're using VB6? Wow, that's some pretty forward thinking school...

Comment: I thought argumentative comments were discouraged here?

Comment: Possible duplicate "How do I read the standard output from a child process in VB6" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571230/how-do-i-read-the-standard-output-from-a-child-process-in-vb6

Answer (score 1):

Try using additional self-closing shell window

```
With New WshShell
    Set oExec = .Exec("%comspec% /C tasklist.exe")
End With
```

Comment: +1 See also similar answer (but more detailed) to very similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571230/how-do-i-read-the-standard-output-from-a-child-process-in-vb6